# js-data observing data changes

Tags: jsdata

I was trying js-data 3.0.0-rc.9. I have few doubts regarding event listeners for data changes and how to use it.

```
Users JSON:

{
  id: '',

  nested : { attr: '', attr2: ""},

  arr : [{},{} ..],

  username : ""
}


store.find('user',1).then(function(data){

      //data - object(record)

      data.on('change',function(data,changes){

         //Object changes

      });

});


store.findAll('user').then(function(data){

   //data - array of objects(records)

   //How to observe any addition/removal in array

});
```

I was able to

1) Listen to the data change done in a object using .on('change') listener.

```
store.get('user',1).username = "Changed name" //It works :D
```

I was not able to

1) Listen to nested data change in a object.

```
store.get('user',1).nested.attr = "something" //It doesn't work. :(
store.get('user',1).set('nested',{}) //It works
```

2) Listen to array data changes (adding, removing)

```
//How to do. ?
```

Correct me if i am doing anything wrong.

It would be so much helpful if there is a complete example regarding the event listeners for those changes.

Thanks in advance.
​